# How to display output in a textbox from another Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have one script with a basic interface, with a textbox in which i display messages. In this script which is still running i call another powershell script, without a separate gui, and i want to display messages in the textbox of the first script which is still running in the background. Is this possible?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).